# free map icon/symbology

Tags: icons, symbols

I want to create a navigation application but can't found any icons/symbols that suitable for my needs, i just hope i can find some icons with consistent style like what we currently see in google maps or garmin.

Thanks

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139944/where-can-one-find-free-software-icons-images

Comment: You might do better to ask your question on a forum that features icon artists or other graphics editing personnel.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. I'd suggest taking a look around on some of the freely-licensed icon resource sites that can be found via a fairly simple google search.

Comment: I disagree that this is not programming related. Nick D., you should put your comment as an answer so you could get credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one interesting icons set with consistent style, not original google maps icons/symbology though. Could anyone help me where i can find all icon used on google maps?

and here the link
http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-icons/

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in making your own icons, I recently found an editor I like. I am not affiliated in any way with the developer:

[IcoFX - The Free Icon Editor](http://icofx.ro/)

Comment: i'm not interested in making the whole icons... yes i know how to do that, but creating over 100 icons with same styles like what google or garmin have was a pain for one-man-job-not-designer like me, btw thanks